# decoding a certain bin file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new the site and incredibly new to this whole subject in general. I apologize if the formatting / question / my English is garbage.

I bought a rowing machine (Concept 2, using the pm5 ), it saves logs to a flash drive if you plug one in. I want to decode them myself and use them for a separate project.

Here is a [sample bin file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17xDilNw5QHa7_v4jQW7vZemd1G3Lb7mI/view?usp=sharing).

I understand how to open the file, and how to work with it normally, however my issue comes when actually translating this particular one into data I can work with.

Here is the data I want to get out of it. This is the result of using their software that auto-converts it.

[image]

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Have you looked for someone else who solved this issue before? Or maybe export from their software to CSV? Otherwise, if you want to work with the file directly, can you post some of the bitstream from the beginning of the file?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, check ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will get better results by following the tips on those articles.

Comment: Are you sure you posted the right link to the bin file? The one linked looks like a  PGP key security ring.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the responses! So far, I've read through people's post that have tried similar things in the past, however I ended up with a gibberish string of numbers from binary_file.read() and trying to decode it any way that'd be meaningful. I honestly don't know what other ways to approach it.

Comment: Yeah I'm sure they are the correct files, I've called the company and asked about it. The tech person pointed out these files as being the entire log that the user has saved to the drive.